# How to display external images from an web-app project in loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

As the title says, I'm trying to display external images in loop into one View in an ASP.NET MVC 4 web-app, on this way :

```
for(int i= 1; true; i++){
   string filepath = "C:\imgs\" + i + ".png";
   do{
       bool exists = filepath.exists;
   } while(!exists);
   displayImage(filepath);
}
```

How to deal this, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
// model
class RenderImageModel
{
   List<string> UserImages {get;set;}

   public RenderImageModel(){
        UserImages = new List<string>();
   }
}

// controller action
public ActionResult Index(){
    var model = new RenderImageModel();
    for(int i= 1; true; i++){
       string filepath = "C:\imgs\" + i + ".png";
       do{
           bool exists = filepath.exists;
       } while(!exists);
       model.UserImages.Add(filepath);
    }

    return View(model);
}

// view
@foreach(imagePath in Model.UserImages){
    <img src='@imagePath' alt />
}
```